# Semantic Issue: Property 'regionMonitoringAvailable' not found

Tags: iphone, core-location, region

I want to check if the user's iphone can use region monitoring, so I check it with regionMonitoringAvailable property in CLLocationManager, however xcode said there is an error:

```
error: Semantic Issue: Property 'regionMonitoringAvailable' not found on object of type 'CLLocationManager *'
```

Here is my code:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;

if (locationManager.regionMonitoringAvailable) {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Anyone know why is this happened? Thanks very much!

Comment: the error is shown in xcode before the app is deployed to the device, so I guess this is not related to iOS device version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a class method, not an instance method. So you need this:

```
if ([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable]) {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```